# Spring batch GZIP ItemWriter/ItemReader

Tags: java, spring, gzip, itemwriter, flatfilereader

I have a Spring boot app, and I wrote some ItemWriter and ItemReaders, for example for JSON files and CSV files.

I want to add a step of compressing to GZIP and decompressing from GZIP.

I wanted to know if it is possible to do as usual with JavaStreams -

If I have some InputStream or OutputStream, I can decorate it with another stream (i.e., another stream can get it in it's constructor and use it), and that way to get all of the streams' functionality easily.

Can it be done with the Spring ItemWriter and ItemReader?

Else, what's the best way to add compressing and decompressing to an existing writers and readers?

Comment: Its is not spring, but perhaps give a library I wrote a spin: https://github.com/skjolber/unzip-csv

Comment: @ThomasRS I don't use only CSV but also JSONs..

Comment: The library is easily extendable to using JSONs.

Comment: @ThomasRS Still, I'd prefer to use a native Spring solution

Comment: Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I see no sample code which I can just copy, compile and run. Are you really expecting everyone to try and magically guess how you use those readers and writers? Apart from that, have you tried [`GZIPInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) and [`GZIPOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there are no other answers yet...let me propose a solution...

It won't be that hard to employ the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to have the output/input compressed or decompressed in a `ItemWriter` and `ItemReader`, respectivly. The *restartability* of the jobs that use those decorated `ItemWriter` and `ItemReader`, however, may be compromised.

> ...what's the best way to add compressing and decompressing to an
>   existing writers and readers?

I'd suggest a separate step - a [`TaskletStep`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep) - with a [Tasklet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) to do just the compression/decompression.